# Rigid body object animation won't preview or play?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigid-body-simulation

I have a simple rigid body animation that won't preview.
The diamond object docent react to the floor as it should when previewing. 
The Other 2 objects in my scene do react correctly. My blender file can
be downloaded here

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jv0fseluf3gsnam/Diamond%20test.blend?dl=0

Can someone help with advice on this please?

[image: rigid body animation that won't preview]

Comment: Works for me with Blender 2.72a

Comment: Thanks but I also downloaded the latest version of Blender but it still dosent work.
The diamond object dosent react to the floor as it should when previewing.
It drops with gravity but it dosent spin or roll once it hits the ground.
It needs to tip over and roll similar to the Ico Sphere..

Comment: That's *very* odd. Looks like a bug to me, best to report it to the tracker. If you don't want to write a report, do you mind if I use your file to report it?

Answer (score 0):

Run the simulation <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> until all frames have been displayed, this causes a real time bake. After that it should work fine.

[image]

Comment: I ended up replacing the diamond with a new one and it works now. Thanks for trying to help.